# App Engine "InvalidURLError: Invalid request URL" though the URL works fine in the browser

Tags: python, google-app-engine, alchemyapi

I'm using an App Engine Task Queue to query [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/).  I send a text string to the task queue.  Each task queue worker queries the AlchemyAPI and processes the results.

After working for ~1500 results, I've started getting endless errors that look like:

```
InvalidURLError: Invalid request URL: http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities?outputMode=json&apikey=xxxx&text=myverylongtexthere
```

Why I'm confused is that if I copy/paste the URL that is supposedly invalid into my browser directly it works fine!

What could possibly cause this kind of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your URL is more than 2048 characters because of `myverylongtexthere`.

```
google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.InvalidURLError
Raised when the URL given is empty or invalid.

Only http: and https: URLs are allowed. The maximum URL length
allowed is 2048 characters. The login/pass portion is not
allowed. In deployed applications, only ports 80 and 443 for http
and https respectively are allowed.
```

Comment: ...and that was exactly it.  I cut the url that I sent to URLFetch to 2048 characters and everything is working perfectly.